# Why aren't radians dimensionless?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, units

```
α = Quantity[-3, ("Radians")/("Seconds")^2];
ω = Quantity[-4, ("Radians")/("Seconds")];
r = Quantity[2, "Feet"];

at = α r
an = ω^2 r
a = Sqrt[an^2 + at^2]
```

results in

$a=\sqrt{\frac{36\text{ft}^2\text{rad}^2}{\text{s}^4}+\frac{1024\text{ft}^2\text{rad}^4}{\text{s}^4}}$

which can't be simplified or reduced. What gives? [The definition of radians](https://www.bipm.org/utils/common/pdf/si-brochure/SI-Brochure-9.pdf) (table on p.137) is such that this should simplify:
$$\textrm{plane angle}\qquad\textrm{radian}\qquad\mathrm{rad}=\frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{m}}$$

and MMA knows it

```
Quantity[1, (("Feet")^2 ("Radians")^2)/("Seconds")^4] == 
Quantity[1, (("Feet")^2 ("Radians")^4)/("Seconds")^4] // Reduce

True
```

Comment: *Mathematica* keeps "radians" so that they can naturally be converted to angular degrees, if desired.

Comment: I see, is there an easy way to simplify that without using QuantityMagnitude or removing the units from the initial values? Each of those solutions introduces a different kind of awkwardness to the workflow.

Comment: @Nasser - I think the point here is that `QuantityMagnitude` is destructive; it removes all units, not just the radians. The desired solution would only remove `"Radians"` but leave `"Feet"` alone

Comment: Angles sometimes may be thought of as legit dimension, but all your familiar formulas should change to really support this idea. It usually denoted as $<\theta>$ to really mean $\theta / (1 \text{rad})$. So it's not correct to have your accelerations to have radians in them, it should be $a_t = <\alpha>  r $ and $a_n = <\omega>^2 r$. Or `at = (α / Quantity[1, "Radians"]) r`, `an = (ω / Quantity[1, "Radians"])^2 r`.

Comment: It looks like the comment I was responding to was deleted so I'll edit that out. I think @swish you have the right answer here, thank you!

Comment: @swish, if you could expand your comment to an answer, I'll upvote it. ;)